# Images in ajax request not being cached

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, jquery, caching

On my site I have successfully cached multiple images (and other file types) using ExpiresActive On in my .htaccess file

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
```

Though this doesn't work on images loaded from an ajax request

```
<div id="ajaxBox"></div>

<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'anotherFile.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        jQuery('#ajaxBox').html(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

If I go to the anotherFile.php itself, then it caches the images. Are there any "special command" of some sort that I should run in the .htaccess file in order to cache images that are loaded through ajax?

Comment: Does your `anotherFile.php` return the binary file (image), or rather HTML that includes a link (in `<img>` tag) to the binary file (image)? Or maybe you are including your images as base64-encoded in the form of URI data strings?

Comment: Interesting. If you manually add an image tag to AjaxBox, does it also not use the cache? E.g. $('#ajaxbox').html('<img src=...'/>); basically, it shouldn't matter "where" the HTML comes from that you put into #ajaxbox. Also, is this behaviour the same across browsers?

Comment: is browser set to `no-cache`?

Comment: Don't know how and why, but I restarted my computer yesterday. And now today when I ran the PageSpeed test again, it worked.